# Simpson's Rule for IVP. Truncation Error proof

Tags: numerical-methods, error-propagation, simpsons-rule, initial-value-problems

Edit: replaced all c's with y's as the c just denotes replacing a series of coupled linear equations Ay with uncoupled equations $\Lambda c$ no biggie.

Im working through the lecture notes for a course on computational modelling of flow and transport. The first Section is on Numerical Methods for IVPs. The text wants to derive order of accuracy by calculating truncation error as

$$ \tau_{\Delta t} = \frac{y^{n+1} - y^{n-1}}{2 \Delta t} - \lambda\big(\frac{1}{6}y^{n+1} + \frac{2}{3}y^n + \frac{1}{6}y^{n-1}\big)\ with\ \lambda\ being\ a\ complex\ number $$

so I tried to calculate the truncation error by expanding taylor series of $ y^{n+1} $ and $ y^{n-1} $

$$ \tau_{\Delta t} = \Big(y + \Delta t y' +\frac{\Delta t^2 y''}{2} +\frac{\Delta t^3 y^{(3)}}{6} +\frac{\Delta t^4 y^{(4)}}{24} +\frac{\Delta t^5 y^{(5)}}{120} - y + \Delta t y' -\frac{\Delta t^2 y''}{2} +\frac{\Delta t^3 y^{(3)}}{6} -\frac{\Delta t^4 y^{(4)}}{24} +\frac{\Delta t^5 y^{(5)}}{120} \Big) \div 2 \Delta t - \lambda \Big( \frac{y}{6} + \frac{\Delta t y'}{6} +\frac{\Delta t^2 y''}{12} +\frac{\Delta t^3 y^{(3)}}{36} +\frac{\Delta t^4 y^{(4)}}{144} +\frac{\Delta t^5 y^{(5)}}{720} + \frac{2 y}{3} + \frac{y}{6} - \frac{\Delta t y'}{6} +\frac{\Delta t^2 y''}{12} -\frac{\Delta t^3 y^{(3)}}{36} +\frac{\Delta t^4 y^{(4)}}{144} -\frac{\Delta t^5 y^{(5)}}{720} \Big)$$

so cancelling obvious terms:

$$ \tau_{\Delta t} = \Big(2\Delta t y' +\frac{\Delta t^3 y^{(3)}}{3} +\frac{\Delta t^5 y^{(5)}}{60} \Big) \div 2\Delta t - \lambda \Big( \frac{y}{3} + \frac{\Delta t^2 y''}{6} + \frac{\Delta t^4 y^{(4)}}{72} + \frac{2y}{3} \Big) $$ $$<=> \tau_{\Delta t} = y' +\frac{\Delta t^2 y^{(3)}}{6} +\frac{\Delta t^4 y^{(5)}}{120} - \lambda y - \frac{\lambda \Delta t^2 y''}{6} - \frac{\lambda \Delta t^4 y^{(4)}}{72} $$ grouping powers of $ \Delta t $

$$ \tau_{\Delta t} = (y' - \lambda y) + \Delta t^2(\frac{y^{(3)}}{6} - \frac{\lambda y''}{6}) + \Delta t^4(\frac{y^{(5)}}{120}  - \frac{\lambda y^{(4)}}{72}) + H.O.T.$$ this is where im stuck. I googled it but all simpson's rule stuff is about integration?? and they just state the truncation error not prove it?? Any Help?

Edit: I think it makes sense if I can assume $ y'' = \lambda y'$ Does anyone know if this is a valid assumption??

Comment: I'm not sure what Simpson's rule is supposed to be in your context either. Anyway, are $c^n$ and $y^n$ the same thing? If that's the case, what you're doing seems right. The order is $2$.

Comment: well order can't be 2 as the leading term is not a function of $\delta t$ $$ \therefore \lim_{\Delta t \to 0} \tau_{\Delta t} \neq 0 $$

Comment: You did not make your notation clear, so I guessed that your $\tau_{\Delta t}$ is not the error, but $\tau_{\Delta t} - (y' - \lambda y)$ is. (I think my guess is right though.)

Comment: $\tau_{\Delta t}$ is the truncation error

Comment: Also order needs to be 4 i think

Comment: I imagine that you are modeling the equation $y' - \lambda y = 0$. If that is the case, $\tau_{\Delta t}$ as written there is NOT the truncation error. You need to subtract from the original ODE to get the truncation error.

Comment: The method is $$ \frac{y^{n+1} - y^{n-1}}{2 \Delta t} = \lambda\big(\frac{1}{6}y^{n+1} + \frac{2}{3}y^n + \frac{1}{6}y^{n-1}\big)\ with\ \lambda\ being\ a\ complex\ number $$ so the truncation error is if u get the difference while replacing numerical approximations with exact values for the components hence the taylor series expansion

Comment: Oh. I think I figured out what you're supposed to do. Replace $y$ with $e^{\lambda t}$.

Comment: Where you write $Δt^4y^{(5)}$ it should be $Δt^4y^{(4)}$ like in the first part of the derivation.

Comment: @LutzL Thanks for spotting that mistake. Fixed it

Answer (score 1):

The method you are exploring is 
$$
\frac{y^{n+1} - y^{n-1}}{2 \Delta t} = \big(\frac{1}{6}f(y^{n+1}) + \frac{2}{3}f(y^n) + \frac{1}{6}f(y^{n-1})\big)
$$
for differential equation $y'=f(y)$. For linear multistep-methods, it is sufficient to explore the approximation error of the most simple non-trivial ODE $y'=f(y)=λy$ with solution $y(t)=C·e^{λt}$. This reduces the error term to
$$
τ_{Δt}=y_n·\left(\frac{e^{λΔt}-e^{-λΔt}}{2Δt}-λ\frac{e^{λΔt}+4+e^{-λΔt}}6\right)
$$
and by inserting the Taylor series of the exponential resp. hyperbolic functions you will see that indeed the lowest remaining power is $(λΔt)^4$.

Comment: In the notes the examples follow the working I'm doing for the other methods without replacing with the solution which theoretically is unknown??? (not sure why actually) The only way I can see of reducing down further is by assuming $y'' = \lambda y'$ which I'm not sure is a valid assumption. I mean I can see ur method works but thats not the way the notes do Euler or CN. Can u refer me to the book that you get ur explanation from or is it from memory. Because wherever I search for Simpson's rule I only get integration stuff

Comment: @AlexByasse This would be easier to find in the more general setting of arbitrary linear multistep methods. This is just the particular one which is inspired by Simpson's rule for integration.

Comment: The analysis of one-step methods like Runge-Kutta methods yields more conditions than those that are exposed by the ODE of the exponential function. Indeed this method does not have a name, in general it seems that nothing much can be gained by having more than the simple difference $(y_{n+1}-y_n)/Δt$ in (or on the left side of) a multistep method. See for instance http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Linear_multistep_method for general information and nice graphics.

Answer (score 0):

Yes take  y'=lambda y;  because we want to minimize truncation error as much as possible, so we want to remove the (delta t) lower degree terms, hence (deltat) 0 power and 2nd degree power terms get cancelled leaving you with truncation error formula I. e., 4th degree terms .

But I think you did a mistake in defining truncation error formula, as the first part of the formula is the differentiation part.