# Discrete derivative formulation by Taylor Expansions

Tags: derivatives, numerical-methods, taylor-expansion

I'm following the paper "Cordova 2014, Comparative Study of two compact finite difference methods".

It states:

Given a discretization of a line by  $x_j = -1 + jh$, where $j = \{ 0, 1, \ldots, N \}$ and $Nh=2$, we have a second order central Finite difference to the first derivative given by:

$$
v'(x_j) - \frac{v_{j+1}-v_{j-1}}{2h} = - \frac{h^2}{6} v'''(x_j) - \frac{h^4}{120} v^{(5)}(x_j) + \cdots
$$
( in fact the paper says $v^{(4)}$ here but I think that the correct is $v^{(5)}$, since adding forward and backwards FD we keep the even terms, and subtracting we keep the odd terms, and as correctly stated in comment the sign should changed in RHS).

That is ok, we get by taking the forward and backwards FD and subtract both.

But then it states:

"A similar Taylor expansion for v′(x) shows the second order difference between v′(xj) and the average value of neighbors as

$$
v'(x_j) - \frac{v'_{j+1}-v'_{j-1}}{2} = \frac{h^2}{2} v'''(x_j) + \frac{h^4}{24} v^{(4)}(x_j) + \cdots
$$"

Then it concludes:

"A simple reduction of above shows that the following equality holds to $O(h^4)$.

$$
\frac{1}{3}V'_{j-1} + \frac{4}{3}V'_{j} + \frac{1}{3}V'_{j+1} = \frac{v_{j+1}-v_{j-1}}{h}
$$

where discrete values $V$ have reaplaced the evaluations of the exact $v'(x)$."

Of course I "believe"  in the author, but I would like to know:

1. How to find the second equation;
2. With them, how to reach the third one.

Just for reference (taken from Cordova et al, A COMPARATIVE STUDY OF TWO COMPACT FINITE DIFFERENCES METHODS: STANDARD VS.MIMETIC)

[image]

Comment: But what is $v'$ ??

Comment: I think that $'$ is the derivation as stated in taylor expansions,  the continuous one. And $v$ is a continuous valued function. But your concern is correct. Let me check.

Comment: It says: "The second order central FD approximation to $v'(x)$ satisfies", then one paragraph later: "A similar Taylor expansion for $v'(x)$ shows the second order difference between $v'(x_j)$ and the average value of neighbors"

Comment: The first equation I could easily achieve.

Comment: If you don't provide the expression of $v'$, there's nothing we can do.

Comment: neither the paper does. $v$ is just any smooth valued function in real space. And $v'$ is the continuous derivative.

Comment: Can you check that there is really a minus sign in the second formula? The "mean value" and the rest of the formula would require $\frac{v'_{j-1}+v'_{j+1}}2$. See also https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1479581/115115 for a similar discussion of this method.

Comment: in fact is $-\frac{v'(x_{j+1})- v'(x_{j-1})}{2}$, with the $x$, that I omitted by mistake.

Comment: Your modifications are benign, the cited article messed up transferring these elementary calculations from paper to computer.

Comment: On second view, even the first formula is wrong in the signs, they probably started with the divided difference formulas $\frac{v_{j+1}-v_{j-1}}{2h}=v_j'+\frac{h^2}6v_j'''+O(h^4)$ and $\frac{w_{j+1}-2w_j+w_{j-1}}{h^2}=w''_j+O(h^2)$, $w_j=v'_j$ and messed up changing the order of terms for a better presentation.

Comment: can you please add all those comments in your answer? Also in my draft here (in paper) I have found $\frac{h^4}{5!}v^{(5)}(x_j)$ not  $\frac{h^4}{5!}v^{(4)}(x_j)$ in the second term on right side of first equation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84517/discussion-between-lin-and-lutzl).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the fundamental theorem of calculus you get
$$
v_{j+1}-v_{j-1}=\int_{x_{j-1}}^{x_{j+1}}v'(x)\,dx
$$
which you can approximate using the Simpson method as
$$
v_{j+1}-v_{j-1}=\frac{2h}6(v'_{j-1}+4v'_j+v'_{j+1})+O((x_{j+1}-x_{j-1})h^4).
$$

That said, the second cited formula is dubious. There is a sign mismatch in the mean value, and the right side should be sign reversed.
$$
\frac{2v'_j-v'_{j-1}-v'_{j+1}}2=v'_j-\frac{v'_{j-1}+v'_{j+1}}2=-\frac{h^2}2v'''_j-\frac{h^4}{24}v^{(4)}_j-...\tag{II}
$$
again by simply inserting the Taylor expansions for $v'(x\pm h)$.

---

Similarly the first formula should be
$$
v'_j-\frac{v_{j+1}-v_{j-1}}{2h}=-\frac{h^2}6v_j'''+O(h^4)\tag{I}
$$

---

After that just combine both equations to eliminate the third derivative terms to again get the method step formula, $(I)-\frac13\,(II)$ gives
\begin{align}
\left(v'_j-\frac{v_{j+1}-v_{j-1}}{2h}\right)-\left(\frac{v'_j}3-\frac{v'_{j-1}+v'_{j+1}}6\right)&=-\frac{h^2}6v_j'''-\frac13\left(-\frac{h^2}2v'''_j\right)+O(h^4)\\
\frac{2v'_j}3+\frac{v'_{j-1}+v'_{j+1}}6&=\frac{v_{j+1}-v_{j-1}}{2h}+O(h^4)
\end{align}

Comment: added a small snippet from original paper for sake of fidelity.